# Write all build logs to a file in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Service) and send as E-mail

Tags: .net, powershell, logging, continuous-delivery, azure-pipelines-build-task

I want to write all the logs generated during build of my solution (as a last step in build definition) and email them as an attachment to other users. I am not able to find any dedicated build task to achieve this. I know they can be downloaded at the end, but I want to add them to a file in build process.

[image]

Alternatively, Is it possible to do it with power-shell scripts in the build task. I am not very familiar with writing powershell scripts :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E-mail the details of a build definition in VSTS (Visual Studio Team Server) to a User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067034/e-mail-the-details-of-a-build-definition-in-vsts-visual-studio-team-server-to)

Comment: You can call the VSTS-Rest-API (via powershell/c#) at the end and download the logs that have been written till then  and then you can build an email and mail the logs.
The current build-id can be retrieved from the environment-variables of the script-hosting process

Comment: @D.J. I was able to get the logs but I was not able to attach them along with an Email. The Email itseldt must be a part of build definition.